# How to test ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, testing, junit, args, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I have never tested with JUnit, not sure what I have to do in this case

```
@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
public void throwsArrayIndexException() {
    ...
}
```

I just have to test that if args[0]==0 in main method, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is expected, I tried with if(args[0]==0){throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException} but didn't work..
I appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class) 
public void throwsArrayIndexException() {
  int [] array = new int[] {};
  int num = array[1];
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)